# If I draw somthing which looks like an old Microsoft Windows desktop Icon, but I draw it myself, how do I the emoji available on an android phone?

Tags: android, text-formatting, sms, emoji, emoji-keyboard

## Short Question

[image: CARTOONS_FOR_YOUNG_PLANTS]

There already exists an emoji for the English word "seedling".

How do I create a library of emoticons which can be used on Microsoft brand cell-phones?

Suppose that I create a `.jpeg` in ***[gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)*** How would I insert that `.jpeg` into at least ***one*** of the following:

> - Short message service (SMS) messages for Microsoft brand and android cellular telephones
> - Multimedia messaging service (MMS) messages for Microsoft brand and android phones
> - text messages for Microsoft brand and android mobile phones
> - rich communication services for phones
> - cellphone Instant Messages for cellular telephones.

[image]

The cartoons I draw I usually make from photo-realistic images....

[image]

After that, it looks similar to, but not the same as, the following image:

After I draw my cartoon, I do not know how to get the cartoon picture into text messages which I send to friends via my cellular telephone.

Comment: No way. Emojis render based on system and OS and you cannot really customize them the way you would change an icon on your own system. Sorry!

Comment: Also posted on Android.SE: [How can I customize my android cellphone so that when I am typing a word in spanish, I suddenly see an emoji and I can insert the emoji?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250454/44325)

Comment: There are messengers that let you add emojis. One is Discord and it can be done in the app. Maybe in the future more apps will allow this.

Comment: Before we even get to the emoji part: don't use JPG for this. JPG is lossy and doesn't support transparency. You probably want to use PNG.

Comment: IN your question you write "How do I create a library of emoticons which can be used on Microsoft brand cell-phones?" but Microsoft phones don't run Android...

Comment: @zomega - doesn't adding emojis on these services still require the added emojis are also installed on the recipient's client?

Comment: mobiles are off-topic

Comment: @Peregrino69 No it doesn't. See https://discord.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-custom-emojis

Comment: Thanks, @zomega. New thing learned = day not wasted :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can send your cartoon only as image… Except if your messaging app has some functionality for what you want (not SMS), most emoji are Unicode characters you can copy for example from [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/seedling/) or [emojiterra](https://emojiterra.com/seedling/) etc.